# what is output ? gcc output is 0. please explain?

Tags: c, switch-statement

gcc compiler output is 0. Why? Shouldn't it be 3?

```
int main()
{
    f(3);
    return 0;
}

int f(int t)
{
    int c;

    switch(t)
    {
    case 2:
        c=2;
    case 3:
        c=3;
    case 4:
        c=4;
    case 5:
        c=5;
    default:
        c=0;
    }
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3: read the manual? Don't be daft! ;)

Comment: @MitchWheat I know, I know... I'm a friggin' elitist with too high expectations! :P

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing the `break;` statement in each of the cases. This leads to control falling through to following case statements and eventually to the `default` case.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `break` after each `case`:

```
switch(t)
{
case 2:
    c=2;
    break;
case 3:
    c=3;
    break;
case 4:
    c=4;
    break;
case 5:
    c=5;
    break;
default:
    c=0;
    break;
}
```

Otherwise the logic "flows through" to the rest of the statements. So when the switch starts executing, initially `c` is assigned 3, but then it continues without the `break` to the next statement in the loop, so immediately gets assigned 4, 5, and then 0. The final value therefore is 0. If you put in the `break`, then the loop terminates at that point and the value of `c` remains 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no break statement in the switch . And the control flows till the end of switch case. The t value is 3 and the control jumps to case 3 and since there is no break there the subsequent lines are executed. i.e c value changes from 3 to 4,5 and then 0.

Read [Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie C Book](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2008/resource/The_C_Programming_Language.pdf)